# Why does mvn compile generate two package lines from my grammar file?

Tags: java, maven, antlr, antlr4

why does my grammar produce two package lines after I compile it with `mvn compile`?

My folder structure is the following:

```
src/main/antlr/eu/niehus/parser/Lexer.g4
src/main/antlr/eu/niehus/parser/Parser.g4
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>eu.niehus</groupId>
  <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>parser</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.9</source>
            <target>1.9</target>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <configuration>
                <visitor>true</visitor>
                <treatWarningsAsErrors>true</treatWarningsAsErrors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>antlr4</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
       <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
       <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

In my Lexer.g4 is the following code:

```
lexer grammar Lexer;

@lexer::header {
package eu.niehus.parser;
}
NUMBER: FLOAT | DIGIT;
LETTER: ('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z');

FLOAT: DIGIT '.' DIGIT+;
DIGIT: [0-9]+ | MINUS [0-9]+;
```

The content of my Parser.g4:

```
parser grammar Parser;

options {
    language = Java;
    tokenVocab = Lexer;
}

@header {
package eu.niehus.parser;
}
addition: NUMBER ('+' NUMBER)+;
```

now if I generate it using mvn compile I get the following source code:

```
// Generated from eu\niehus\parser\Lexer.g4 by ANTLR 4.7

package eu.niehus.parser;

package eu.niehus.parser;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa.DFA;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.*;
```

and it contains two package lines. How can I prevent Maven from generating two package lines?

I've already tried having no @header statement in my Parser/Lexer and it removes one of the package lines. But I don't think that this is how it's supposed to be handled

Comment: Have you tried to use `@parser::header { ...` instead of `@header {...` for the parser part ?

Answer (score 0):

one of the package statements is due to the location of your .g4 files (src/main/antlr/eu/niehus/parser/).

The other is due to the package statement in the header portion of your .g4 file